# Saving Image Path in PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql, file, path, save

I working on a project where I have a products table where I upload some images (3) for a each product. I am dealing with a problem to upload the files, because in the Database is only saving the dir and not the file . With this code an images I can explain it better. I just want to upload the file and save it the path, so i can later show it in the producto layout page and others.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div class="col form-group">
          <label class="form-label" for="imag1_prod"><b>Imagen 1: </b></label>
          <input type="file" class="filestyle" id="imag1_prod" name="imag1_prod" alt="Imagen del Producto 1" data-btnClass="btn-primary">
        </div>
```

I am working in a CRUD and I add the products through a Modal.

**Next, My PHP: THE EDITED CODE**

```
    <?php

require_once ("../paginas/conexion_bd.php"); //Contiene Funcion que Conecta a la Base de Datos

// escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
if(isset($_FILES['imag1_prod']['name'])) {

//post variables
$ident_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["ident_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$ident_cate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["ident_cate"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$nombr_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["nombr_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$desco_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["desco_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$desla_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["desla_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$preci_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["preci_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$pesoo_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["pesoo_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$taman_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["taman_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$stock_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["stock_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$estad_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["estad_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));


//get filename
$filename = $_FILES['imag1_prod']['name'];

//rename file
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["imag1_prod"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);

//set path
$target_dir = "../imagen/productos/";

//upload files in folder
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imag1_prod']['tmp_name'], "$target_dir/$newfilename");

//rename file with directory name
$filenamedirectory = $target_dir/$newfilename;

$statu_prod = 1;

    // Registrar en la Base de Datos
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabma_prod(ident_prod, ident_cate, nombr_prod, desco_prod, desla_prod, preci_prod, pesoo_prod, taman_prod, stock_prod, estad_prod, imag1_prod, statu_prod) VALUES ('$ident_prod',(SELECT ident_cate FROM tabma_cate WHERE ident_cate = '$ident_cate'),'$nombr_prod','$desco_prod','$desla_prod','$preci_prod','$pesoo_prod','$taman_prod','$stock_prod','$estad_prod','$filenamedirectory','$statu_prod') ";


    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    // Si ha sido Agregado Exitosamentee
    if ($query) {
        $messages[] = "El producto ha sido registrado con éxito.";
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Lo sentimos, el registro falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.";
    }
    }   

if (isset($errors)){        
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>Error!</strong> 
            <?php
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                        echo $error;
                    }
                ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    if (isset($messages)){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
                <?php
                    foreach ($messages as $message) {
                            echo $message;
                        }
                    ?>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".alert").delay(2000).slideUp(200, function() {
      $(this).alert('close');
    });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

It's designed to upload 3 images per product, but for now only one for testing.

**Now, some images about how it looks and the errors:**

[image: Here the Errors that i get, dont know why undefined index if i am declaring as an]

**And here its what is already saving in the database:**

[image: As we can see, only saving the target_dir]

Seeing this, the mistake has to be with the declaration of "imag1_prod" but i dont know why its wrong.

Hope can help me!

Best Regards to Everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to save only directory and product name in the database and upload file to folder for later retrieval. So kudos for using good practices.

As you've guessed, the problem is that your app is not recognizing the variable :

```
$imag1_prod=$_FILES["imag1_prod"][ "name" ];
```

Because you are renaming it here :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imag1_prod"][" tmp_name "]
```

The other issue here is that you are forgetting to store the filename as well as the directory.

Try this :

```
if(isset($_FILES['imag1_prod']['name'])) {

//post variables
$ident_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["ident_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$ident_cate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["ident_cate"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$nombr_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["nombr_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$desco_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["desco_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$desla_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["desla_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$preci_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["preci_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$pesoo_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["pesoo_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$taman_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["taman_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$stock_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["stock_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$estad_prod = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["estad_prod"],ENT_QUOTES)));


//get filename
$filename = $_FILES['imag1_prod']['name'];

//rename file
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["imag1_prod"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);

//set path
$target_dir = "../imagen/productos/";

//upload files in folder
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imag1_prod']['tmp_name'], "$target_dir/$newfilename");

//rename file with directory name
$filenamedirectory = $target_dir/$newfilename;

$statu_prod = 1;

// Registrar en la Base de Datos
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabma_prod(ident_prod, ident_cate, nombr_prod, desco_prod, desla_prod, preci_prod, pesoo_prod, taman_prod, stock_prod, estad_prod, imag1_prod, statu_prod) 
VALUES ('$ident_prod',(SELECT ident_cate FROM tabma_cate WHERE ident_cate = '$ident_cate'),'$nombr_prod','$desco_prod','$desla_prod','$preci_prod','$pesoo_prod','$taman_prod','$stock_prod','$estad_prod','$filenamedirectory','$statu_prod') ";
}
```

Also make sure you use [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to avoid SQL injections when performing database operations.

Comment: Ok I understand, now it seems to work better. But now, when I hit the submit button, its not inserting the data, nothing happens. No errors and nothing.

Comment: I thinks that its to be with "if(isset($_FILES['imag1_prod']['name'])) {"..... where it supposed to close? I edited the code you can see it completed.

Comment: @CarlosAgustinGuanipaAlvarez : Could you make it work? If you get a blank page something gone incredibly wrong. Add this at the top of your page for error reporting : `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('html_errors', 0);ini_set('log_errors',-1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Also, is the file uploading to the folder? The `if(isset)` closes at the end of the insert statement.

Comment: Thanks! You help really help me!. This was fine, the thing was with the Ajax! I forgot to mentionted that, I got to change to formData variable to get the $_POST and $_FILES, not only the $_POST. By the rest, everything all right! Thanks!